# Cannot solve ECONNRESET when using https://ninjaweb.xyz/ to proxy http requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, http-proxy

### Issue Description:

- I figured out that internally, this endpoint is called: `https://ninjaweb.xyz/index.php/?cdURL=https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/hello`
- But the response can be received only when I input the destination url in the webite's input field.
- I am using axios for making the request

### What I want to achieve

I will be able to use the endpoint from my nodejs application`https://ninjaweb.xyz/index.php/?cdURL=https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/hello` and get the same result as calling `https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/hello`

Any suggestion accepted gratefully. Thanks in advance.